# Chrome adding weird padding between inside of div and my CSS display: table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, padding

I am attempting to wrap a CSS table ( `div`,  class of `myTable`,  `display:table`) inside a `div` (class of `index` and `display:block`) but am having an issue with Chrome. Chrome is adding about one pixel's worth of padding between the wrapper and the table it is containing.  This does not occur in Edge, Safari or Firefox.

What is odd is that Chrome only adds this padding:

1. on the right side, and
2. and random widths.

You can see it below, or in this codepen: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/xgRXMZ

#### No Weird Padding: the right hand border is truly red:

[image: no weird padding]

#### Weird Padding: The right hand side adds padding, appearing purple due to background color of blue:

[image: no weird padding]

#### The blue padding is visible in this zoomed image:

[image: Padding up close]

If you adjust your browser windows to different widths you will see that at some widths it is fine, with no added padding, and at others the weird padding appears on the right, you'll see the right edge turn purple.

But this change is hard to see.This purple that appears on the rigth is not a true purple, but only appears as purple. The background color inside the container is blue, and at only one pixel the eye mixes it with the red border of the containing div. You can verify this if you change the background-color of containing div (`.index`) in the CSS to any color you want.

Please do not suggest I remove the table and just display the two as table-cells. This would work if I only had one table, but actually I have a bunch of tables I am stacking vertically inside this wrapper. **It is important that I keep the wrapper for both cells as (`display: table`),** because I actually have other rows that are in this container that I am also displaying as tables. If I display them all as `table-cell`, all of my rows end up on the same line, which is not what I want.

I have recognized that this problem occurs even if there is only one table, as you can see in my example, it is not the product of stacking tables inside a div.

Can any of you help me to get Chrome to behave and stop adding that weird padding?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1: The weird padding only occurs if I have my `border-right` present. If i remove that border, the padding never appears.

UPDATE 2: If I change the row wrapper to `display: block`, I eliminate the mysterious gap, but I'll leave the question open, in case anyone wants a `display:table`friendly solution.

UPDATE 3: The only answers that have been submitted as of yet involve javaScript. Since I did not specify that I wanted a pure CSS solution, I'll give the user who submitted a functional answer credit, but if you like a challenge and see this question, please feel free to drive to derive a pure CSS solution. Thank you!

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


article {
  width: 75%;
}

.index {
  
  background-color: blue;
  display:block;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.index > div {
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}



.myTable > div {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 
.myTable {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.myTable > div {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}

.myTable > div.date {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.index .excerpt {
  width: 92%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<article id="post-1" >
  <div class="index">

<div class="myTable">

 <div class="date">   
     1 .10 .2017   </div> 

 <div class="excerpt">
  <p>Notice there is about 1px padding to the right of this table and its containing div, but only at certain screen widths </p>
<p>over there -----></p>
   <p>You'll see that when the unwanted padding appears (at random widths), the right border of the div and this table appears to turn purple. This purple is not a true purple, but only appears as purple. The background color  inside the container is blue, and at only one pixel the eye mixes it with the red border of the containiing div. You can verify this if you change the background-color of ".index" in the css to any color you want. </p>
   
   
   <p><span style="color:orange"> It is important that I keep the the wrapper for both cells as (display: table)</span>, because I actually have other rows that are in this container that I am also displaying as tables. If I display them all as table-cells, they all end up on the same line, which is not what I want.  </p>
     <p>However, I have recognized that this problem occurs even if there is only one table.</p>

   
     <p>This only occurs in Chrome, not Edge, Safari or Firefox.</p>


  </div> 

 </div>

  </div>


</article>

  
  
  
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: Hard to see.. kind of looks like anti-aliasing between the grey/black and red to me, not actual padding or space.

Comment: Change the background-color of `.index` to green- it will be greenish, change it to white, it will be whitish, it really is the padding color.

Comment: I don't see this..tested on Windows 10 in latest Chrome 55, The text is always flush with the red line, no matter how many times i resize the browser from full viewport 1080px to 100px, Even tried it zoomed to 150% while resizing. Could this possible be only affecting Chrome on Mac?

Comment: windows 10 here, Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Comment: Same thing. I see the color change, but really still looks like a possible 1/2 pixel anti-aliasing issue to me. Honestly I'd have to specifically be looking for it to even notice it.

Comment: guys, i tested it - change the color of .index's padding inside the CSS - it the  padding showing, its not the way it is mixing the gray of the inside div with the red border. Try white, and it will look pink.

Comment: white... anti-aliased to red = pink. Set the background in Index to the red or grey and you would never see it. Not discounting the issue. I do see it. But I suspect it's more of a Chrome issue than a construction issue you can fix, unless you want to not use `display: table`

Comment: wait let's pause. you agree the added color is from the wrapper's background and not from a mixing of the inner table's background color mixing with the wrapper's border, right?

Comment: ok, so it is chrome, what can i do to fix it? One idea I had is to change the wrappers from display tables to display blocks, and I think that will work.

Comment: Ok, so I further isolated this issue. The gap disappears if I remove the right border on the wrapper. Chrome is adding padding when it adds the right border. If i remove that code, everything is flush.

Comment: Both of those borders in the screenshots look red to me.

Comment: Look only on the right border , and with your glasses on. :)

Comment: By the way please don't be distracted by my above comment about the border. Removing the border does not solve the issue. :)

Comment: If people have trouble seeing the blue line, might I suggest changing the background of the .index div to white and its right border color to #282828. Then it's definitely visible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var article = document.getElementById('post-1');
article.style.width = Math.round(article.parentElement.clientWidth * 3 / 4) + 'px';

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  article.style.width = Math.round(article.parentElement.clientWidth * 3 / 4) + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
article {
  width: 75%;
}
.index {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.index > div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
.myTable > div {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myTable {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
.myTable > div {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
.myTable > div.date {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.index .excerpt {
  width: 92%;
}
```

```html
  <article id="post-1">
    <div class="index">

      <div class="myTable">

        <div class="date">
          1 .10 .2017</div>
        <div class="excerpt">
          <p>Notice there is about 1px padding to the right of this table and its containing div, but only at certain screen widths</p>
          <p>over there -----></p>
          <p>You'll see that when the unwanted padding appears (at random widths), the right border of the div and this table appears to turn purple. This purple is not a true purple, but only appears as purple. The background color inside the container
            is blue, and at only one pixel the eye mixes it with the red border of the containiing div. You can verify this if you change the background-color of ".index" in the css to any color you want.</p>


          <p><span style="color:orange"> It is important that I keep the the wrapper for both cells as (display: table)</span>, because I actually have other rows that are in this container that I am also displaying as tables. If I display them all as table-cells,
            they all end up on the same line, which is not what I want.</p>
          <p>However, I have recognized that this problem occurs even if there is only one table.</p>


          <p>This only occurs in Chrome, not Edge, Safari or Firefox.</p>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </article>
```

Comment: If would be better if you explained what you changed from my snippet, and why you changed that. To the casual eye it looks just like you copied it over and then hit post without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rounding problem, caused by a container with a width of 75%. Apparently the table isn't good at filling a space of, say, 657.75 pixels fully.

A simple workaround would be to give the parent div the same background color as its border color, or the same as the table's background color. But you probably already considered those...

The real solution is to round the width of the article to whole pixels, so that the table is able to fill it neatly without having three quarter pixel left over.
This can't be done with CSS, so we need JavaScript.

```js
var article = document.getElementById('post-1');
article.style.width = Math.round(article.parentElement.clientWidth * 3 / 4) + 'px';

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  article.style.width = Math.round(article.parentElement.clientWidth * 3 / 4) + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
article {
  width: 75%;
}
.index {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.index > div {
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
.myTable > div {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myTable {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
.myTable > div {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
.myTable > div.date {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.index .excerpt {
  width: 92%;
}
```

```html
<article id="post-1">
  <div class="index">

    <div class="myTable">

      <div class="date">
        1 .10 .2017</div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        <p>Notice there is about 1px padding to the right of this table and its containing div, but only at certain screen widths</p>
        <p>over there -----></p>
        <p>You'll see that when the unwanted padding appears (at random widths), the right border of the div and this table appears to turn purple. This purple is not a true purple, but only appears as purple. The background color inside the container is
          blue, and at only one pixel the eye mixes it with the red border of the containiing div. You can verify this if you change the background-color of ".index" in the css to any color you want.</p>


        <p><span style="color:orange"> It is important that I keep the the wrapper for both cells as (display: table)</span>, because I actually have other rows that are in this container that I am also displaying as tables. If I display them all as table-cells,
          they all end up on the same line, which is not what I want.</p>
        <p>However, I have recognized that this problem occurs even if there is only one table.</p>


        <p>This only occurs in Chrome, not Edge, Safari or Firefox.</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work on this. I think you may have been right about the cause of the problem, but your fix did not work. I still had the mysterious padding. I gave credit to the other user. Do you think i should send a bug report to google?  This doesn't occur on other browsers.

Comment: That's strange; on my computer, my solution works better than the other one; the other one has a blue line at the bottom of the table! Oh well.

Comment: Yes he has a blue line, but i think that is because i don't have a border there.  Yours still has the disappearing padding on the right, it doesn't seem to have solved it.